# Can record counts be added to paginated grids yet?

Tags: acumatica

According to this article, they cannot at the time it was made, which was 2018:
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/07/page-number-on-acumatica-grid.html

Are there any plans to implement this customization for the future or any way to do this differently today? A customer would like grids on base Acumatica pages to be paginated with record counts.

Comment: As far as I know in any version >= 19R2 the GIs are showing the total number of the records by default.

Comment: It's not for a GI though, but you are correct. It is for a detail grid in a BLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Status Field of the Grid for this.
So the idea is to calculate the quantity of the records in the View Delegate in the Graph and then just set it as the "StatusField" of the Grid in the same way as Acumatica is calculating the Available and Available for Shipments in the Sales Order Details grid.

[image]

Comment: What would I put into the Status Field that would show the current record count and position?

Comment: @EricP. There is no out-of-box value for that. You need to calculate the numbers, build the string and set it as StatusField to the grid similar to what Acumatica is doing for Availability information.https://ibb.co/P6tgxjk

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark your answer as certified. I'll inform the customer and see how they want to move forward. I appreciate your time Samvel!